# Show that the normalizer of a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $A_{n}$ contains an odd permutation

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $P$ be a $p$−Sylow subgroup of $A_{n}, n ≥ 3$, Show that $N_{G}(P)$ contains
an odd permutation.

The problem is I can pull some information from this question but can't join the dots.

I know that a $p$-Sylow subgroup of a group of order $N$ is a subgroup of $N$ with order $p$ that divides $N$.

I know the order of an alternating group $A_{n}$ is $\frac{n!}{2}$

And I remember something along the lines of odd permutations having an even number of 2-cycles when broken down.

But I can't connect the dots.

Does anyone have and ideas how to answer this question?

Comment: You have not said what $G$ is.

Comment: I was also confused about this. I copied the question word for word. I'm assuming $G = A_n$

Comment: It can't be $G=A_n$ because you are supposed to be proving that $N_{A_n}(P)$ is an odd permutation. It should be $G=S_n$.

Comment: That seems to make sense since $A_{n}$ is the group of even permutations. Still not sure where to go from here.

Comment: More generally, this is an example of Frattini's argument: if $G$ is a finite group, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $P$ is a Sylow subgroup of $H$, then $G = N_G(P)H$.  Frattini's argument is a useful lemma in its own right, but proving it yourself is also a good exercise for understanding the power of Sylow's theorem.

Comment: @SteveD Please move your comment into an answer that the OP can accept to take this out of the unsolved list.

Comment: @StephenMeskin: Done.

Answer (score 1):

For $p$ odd, a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $A_n$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_n$.  Since $A_n$ is normal, it contains all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $S_n$.  Thus,

$$ [S_n:N_{S_n}(P)]=n_p(S_n)=n_p(A_n)=[A_n:N_{A_n}(P)]$$

This shows $[N_{S_n}(P):N_{A_n}(P)]=2$, so $N_{S_n}(P)$ is not contained in $A_n$, and hence contains an odd permutation.

For $p=2$, a Sylow 2-subgroup of $A_n$ (call it $P$) has index $2$ in a Sylow 2-subgroup of $S_n$ (call it $Q$).  Thus $P$ is normal in $Q$, so $Q\le N_{S_n}(P)$.  Since $Q$ is not contained in $A_n$, it contains an odd permutation.